# Does exhaustaffect Karthus damage while he is undead?

Tags: league-of-legends

So let's say you are playing with Exhaust and you kill Karthus while he is Exhausted. Will his damage be reduced by Exhaust in his passive if you killed him while exhaust was active?

Comment: Since Karthus is untargetable in the afterlife, you can't exhaust him.

Comment: I understand that what i just mean is if you get the exhaust and kill him 1 second after for the 1.5 s left on exhaust is the damage modifier still in effect

Comment: I dont think so because he technically dies and then comes back for a brief period. I have no evidence supporting it, but I am certain that exhaust's effects only last up until death.

Comment: @slow_excellence: oh yeah that makes sense.

Comment: No. Karthus is untargettable and is instantly free from any CC when his passive skill is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  When Karthus dies and his passive is activated, all CC is removed and he is untargetable for the duration of the effect.

"Upon dying, Karthus enters a spirit form and becomes invulnerable and untargetable, allowing him to continue casting spells at no cost for 7 seconds."
-From the League of Legends Wiki.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Karthus